# How can I load this json file successfully?

Tags: python-3.7, discord.py

I'm building a discord bot that will play cards against humanity. The issue is that when I try to load the JSON file, the program doesn't work.

```
`@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def loadCards(ctx):
  with open('wcards.json') as f:
    wtcards = json.load(f)
  with open('bcards.json') as f:
    bkcards = json.load(f)
  if len(wtcards) > 1 and len(bkcards) > 1:
    await ctx.send('Cards Loaded')`
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"? Do you get errors? What is the output?

Comment: It says 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need to use the read and write parameters when using open().
e.g.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def loadCards(ctx):
  with open('wcards.json', 'r') as f:
    wtcards = json.load(f)
  with open('bcards.json', 'r') as f:
    bkcards = json.load(f)
  if len(wtcards) > 1 and len(bkcards) > 1:
    await ctx.send('Cards Loaded')
```